# Apply CSS styling to text content either before or after a specific element

Tags: css, sass

Given the following HTML markup:

```
<li class="lrn-text-word-wrap" tabindex="-1" data-selector="suggested-tag">
  12345: <strong>Han</strong> Solo
</li>
```

Is it possible to apply styling **with only css** to remove the `12345:`  text content?

I do not have control over the markup so cannot make changes there and really don't want to have to resort to JS.

What I'm trying to achieve here is to use CSS to only show the words "Han Solo" rather that "12345: Han Solo"

The reason the `<strong>` tag only wraps "Han" is this is part of an autocomplete and the user has types "Hans" The markup shows a matching result, highlighting the text the user typed, which is fine, but I need to be able top hide the "key" part.

I have put together the following SCSS, but this only allows the `<strong>` text to remain whereas we need to also show everything after the `<strong>` too.

```
[data-selector='suggested-tag'] {
  font-size: 0px
  strong {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if there is a way to select just text nodes via CSS this would probably be sufficient.

Any suggestions to how to approach this would be greatly received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a try with a grid-layout and set the first column to 0 and a `background` to the `strong` element to hide what overflows from that first column.

---

**Explanation:** grid will wrap every portion of text inside a virtual cell. If html tags are standing among the text it will produce as many portions.

Your example will produce 3 cells , 1 virtual for the text standing ahead the `<strong>` tag , the second element will be the `<strong>` tag itself and the third(virtual) will be the text standing after that `<strong>` tag.

---

here is the idea:

```css
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style:none;
}

li.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0 repeat(2, minmax(3em, max-content));
  justify-content: start;
  background: lightgray;
}

.grid strong {
  background: inherit;
  padding:0 0.2em;
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="grid"> 12345: <strong>Han</strong> Solo</li>
  <li> 12345: <strong>Han</strong> Solo</li>
</ul>
```

---

edit for the case commented below

> ...  We know that there will always be a `:` ...

Javascript will be required at that point to remove the unwanted portions of the text on the fly.

here an example .

```js
let lis = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
[...lis].forEach((txtCntnt) => {
  let content= txtCntnt.innerHTML;
  content = content.substring(content.indexOf(":") + 1);
  txtCntnt.innerHTML=content;
});
```

```css
strong{color:purple}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> 12345 keep that han hu!: Han<strong> Sol</strong>o</li>
  <li> 12345 of any lenght: <strong>Han</strong> Solo</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly when the searched text matches the start of the string we want, however what if we searched for something like "Sol" - the resultant HTML is that case becomes:
`<li class="lrn-text-word-wrap" tabindex="-1" data-selector="suggested-tag">
  12345: Han <strong>Sol</strong>o
</li>`
In the above case, the text show is "Solo" whereas really we want to see "Hans Solo" at that point. We know that there will always be a `:` character if that is of any use?

Comment: @HughL in such a case, you will need javascript to strip away that portion of unwanted text. CSS cannot do this ;) (nor sass that never sees the document and only produces plain CSS)

Comment: yes, this was indeed what we ended up doing unfortunately - we used a mutation observer to check for the DOM changing and regex to strip out the unwanted text from the text content. Thanks for your help on the original question though. You learn something new everyday!